# Error when trying to solve a quadratic? equation via python

Tags: python, math

First of all; english is not my main language so bare in mind. (The text in the script is in norwegian, I will try to translate as well as possible)

I am trying to create a python script that solves a second degree equation or a quadratic? equation I think. If i understand it correctly I should use cmath module to be able to solve complex roots, however, I havent got that far in my class yet and it is my task to only use math module and return a answer that looks something like this (if the roots are complex): "There is no real solution".

Also, when using normal math module I get returned a "math domain error" when trying to for example put a = 6, b = 11 and c = 32.

Thank you in advance.

Edward

Trying to use a if/elif/else thingy, have tried cmath (it returns a waaaay to long and unreadable answer)

My code is here under this (hopefully I have pasted it correctly, sorry in advance:

```
#Importerer math
import math

print("Programmet skal løse andregradslikningen ")
print("ax^2 + bx + c = 0 ved hjelp av abc-formelen")
print("Skriv inn verdiene for a, b og c.")

a = float(input('a = '))
b = float(input('b = '))
c = float(input('c = '))

d = (b**2) - (4*a*c)

sol1 = (-b+math.sqrt(d))/(2*a)
sol2 = (-b-math.sqrt(d))/(2*a)

if d < 0:
    print("Likningen har ingen løsning")
elif d==0:
    print(f"Løsning x = {-b/(2*a)}")
else:
    print("Løsningen er")
    print(f"x = {sol1}, og x= {sol2}")
```

Comment: `math.sqrt` isn't defined for negative arguments. You have to use `cmath.sqrt` instead. What exactly is "too long and unreadable"?

Comment: I don't see a question here. There's a homework assignment, and some code. But no question. Is the code failing? Is it raising an exception? Is it producing bad results? A syntax error? Nearby horses catch fire when you run it? See [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @Barmar, I have been trying to make this work for a week and I am stuck.. While I fully understand what you are saying, making someone else do my homework is not the deal here. I want to learn a effective way of doing something like this, and did not find a fix that matches my problem, hence why I started a new thread. Thank you anyways,

Comment: That "waaaay to long and unreadable answer" is called a traceback, and seeing the complete traceback is absolutely critical to getting a correct answer here.

Comment: @chepner If i use cmath the answer i get i something along the lines of this: -1.024 + 0000000.281j, which is hard to read (for me because I am dyslectic) I want it to be rounded, but haven't gotten both the round() or the format.sol1 function to work..

Comment: @TimRoberts but is it incorrect to add the traceback together so that I get returned only a single answer looking something like this?: x = , and/or x = ?

Comment: If d is negative, the roots are complex. If d is non-negative the roots are real.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk So that is why math.sqrt fails? Because d is negative, and therefore the roots are complex (which means normal math.sqrt doesn't know how to solve it) so I will have to use cmath for it to be able to return that the equation has no real solution?

Comment: It's not clear what you would round it to. You can't just "round" it to a nearby real number.

Comment: Yes, if d is negative then using cmath.sqrt() should be easiest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check if `d` is negative *before* you try to call `math.sqrt(d)`, so you don't get an error.

```
d = (b**2) - (4*a*c)

if d < 0:
    print("Likningen har ingen løsning")
elif d==0:
    print(f"Løsning x = {-b/(2*a)}")
else:
    sol1 = (-b+math.sqrt(d))/(2*a)
    sol2 = (-b-math.sqrt(d))/(2*a)
    print("Løsningen er")
    print(f"x = {sol1}, og x= {sol2}")
```

Comment: Oooh so before the sol1 and sol2 definition I need to check if d will be negative, and return a print("Because d is negative the equation has no real solution"?

Comment: That's correct.